# how to check if there is the next() element

Tags: jquery

This code check if the class before `.trackOn` is called "sideOn" :

```
if($('.trackOn').prev().attr('class')=="sideOn") alert("before=sideOn");
```

Now, I'd like to check if after `.trackOn` (using `.next()`) there isnt any div. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Node.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName) to get the element's node name.

```
if ($('.trackOn').next().get(0).nodeName != 'DIV') alert('Not before a div');
```

Please note that this is always uppercased.

---

Unrelated to the question, using [`jQuery.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) is better than checking the sole attribute value because it can contain more than one class.

Comment: what do you mean with `it can contain more than one class` ?

Comment: If the element has something like `class="sideOn otherClass"` then your strict `=='sideOn'` check will fail. Better use `if($('.trackOn').prev().hasClass('sideOn'))`

Comment: ah ok...yeah in any case I put only 1 class for only div, I prefeer :) I'll use this hasClass(), is good! thanks