# jQuery see if next element (not sibling) exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my HTML code:

```
<select class="grid_3 required jobData valid" id="clli" name="clli" style="font-size: 10px; border: none;">
<option value="0">Select One...</option>
    <option value="905"></option>
    <option value="931">0</option>
    <option value="1">ABRDMSES</option>
</select>
<img alt="This data has been changed!" title="This data has been changed!" src="images/caution.png">
<img alt="This data has been changed!" title="This data has been changed!" src="images/caution.png">
<img alt="This data has been changed!" title="This data has been changed!" src="images/caution.png">
<select class="grid_3 required jobData" id="job_status" name="job_status" style="font-size: 10px; border: none;">
<option value="0">Select One...</option>
</select>
```

When a `$('.jobData').change();` occurs, I slap a **caution image** next to it to warn the user that there are changes to be saved. However, if they make more than one change to the same element, I first want to see if there is already a **caution image** there before sending a new one. Any theories/methods on how to just scope out the next (but not `$.next()`) element?

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking some combination of .after() and .is() might do the trick...

Comment: I have downvoted this question as 1. this question has been asked n times on stackoverflow. 2. It's unclear too, there are 3 `img` elements that are siblings of the select element and the question says _not sibling_.

Comment: @undefined: If it has been asked "n" times, I would have appreciated a URL to one of the other occurrences that may have had a correct answer. And, yes, the `<img>` elements are NOT siblings of the `<select>` elements, so it's quite syntactically correct.

Comment: @DevlshOne But in your posted markup they are. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301613/how-can-i-check-the-type-of-the-next-element?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765701/how-to-check-if-there-is-the-next-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$().one` to trigger handler only once. This way you won't need to check it.

```
$('select').one('change', function(e) {  });
```

If there is more than one selects in result set of selector, one would be applied to each of them , and as soon as you need to show image after each select, it will perfectly suit here.

Comment: Man, you would have hit a homerun on this one except I worded my question wrong. I'm actually using $('.jobData').change(); to trigger my caution images. There are literally dozens of select tags on the page or this would be so brilliant!!

Comment: Will it really apply a ".one()" for EACH select statement? That would be superb. Let me go try it..

You are a genius, sir!!! Works beautifully!!

Comment: Well it will, otherwise you'll just do `$(selector).each(function(){ $(this).one(handler) })`

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting to wrap the cautions images by a div tag and do a count on image tags there.

Eg,

```
<div id="cautions">
    <img src="caution.png" />
</div>
```

In js

```
if($('#cautions img').length) != 0)
    // insert image
```

Comment: Again, if I didn't have dozens of "select"s on the page, this would be great!